# How would I fix this? node.js prompt error

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, prompt

I was trying to insert a record in the table of employees, then I got this error in node.js(vs code).
So, I googled it and he said, "Prompt and window are not defined in the node environment."
What does that mean? Can't I use a prompt in node.js?

This is my code:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "crud"
});

con.connect((error)=>{
    if(error)
        throw(error);
    console.log("Connected to dataBase");

let id = prompt("Enter id: ");
let name = prompt('Enter employee name: ');
let sal = prompt('Enter sal: ');

var sql = "INSERT INTO employee (e_id, e_name, e_sal) VALUES ("+Number(id)+ ", '"+name+"','" +Number(sal)+ "')";

con.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record successfully inserted in the table.");
});
});
```

Comment: `prompt` is only defined in browsers. If you want to input some data to your nodejs application you could either use the builtin [`Readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module or install some other module available at https://npmjs.org providing that functionality  (typically those modules are just convinience wrappers around the builtin readline)